# question about ax,al registers x86 64bits asm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers

I start to learn x86 64bit programming and I'm confused about a thing.

I know that numbers on 8 bits can have values in the range -128 to 127 for signed numbers and 0 to 255 for unsigned numbers, and numbers of 16 bits can have values in the range -32768 to 32767

Now my question: Let's say I have a register AX which is a 16bits register and AH which is 8 bits register. Now, what values should AX take such that the instruction `neg AL` to set the overflow flag to be 1 ?
a) 8000h b)255 c)7FFFh d)0 e)FFFF f) -127

I know that I can put in AX register numbers between -32768 and 32767 but how AL register is modifying when I put a numbers in AX? For example, I write `mov ax,-127` which is fine, how AL is modifying?

Comment: `AL` is the low 8 bits of `AX`, and `AH` is the top 8 bits. `mov ax, -127` loads `0xff81` so `AL=0x81`. `NEG` will only set `OF` if `AL=-128=0x80` which means you can load `AX` with values of the form `0x??80`

Comment: None of the listed values matches that. You can verify with a debugger.

Comment: Did you mean `neg ah`, since you mentioned AH earlier in the sentence?